# Envío automático de email con excel

Tags: excel, vba

Necesito hacer una macro que envíe un correo electrónico automáticamente.
 El problema es que parece que todo el código está bien, no aparece ningún error en tiempo de ejecución, pero no envía el correo.

Podría alguien decirme si ve algún fallo??

```
    Public Sub correoeVpagsPDF() 'Envia correo electrónico con hoja activa en pdf
'***--Declaración de variables--***
Dim nfac, cliente, Email, ruta, LIBRO, ahora, ArchivoPdf As String
Dim ProgCorreo, CorreoSaliente As Object 'Objetos de outlock

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False 'Excel no refresca la pantalla
    .EnableEvents = False 'Deshabilita eventos
    .DisplayAlerts = False 'Deshabilita las alertas
End With

Set nfac = Range("D2") 'Nombre de la orden
Set cliente = Range("B2") 'Nombre del técnico
Set Email = Range("G3") 'Email del remitente

ruta = "E:\Para copia de seguridad\Quique\" 'Ruta para guaradar el archivo
ahora = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Now(), "dd.mm.yy- hh.mm") 'Consigue la fecha actual
LIBRO = nfac & "-" & cliente & "-" & ahora & ".pdf" 'nombre del pdf
ArchivoPdf = ruta & LIBRO 'ruta con el nombre del archivo incluido

'**--Objeto outlook--**
Set ProgCorreo = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set CorreoSaliente = ProgCorreo.CreateItem(0)

'**--Crea el pdf con la hoja activa y lo guarda en la carpeta seleccionada--**
With ActiveSheet
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ArchivoPdf, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
End With

On Error Resume Next

'**--Envio de email--**
With CorreoSaliente
    .To = Email 'Dirección
    .CC = "Correo@prueba" 'Copia
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Envío de su factura nº " & nfac 'Asunto
    .Body = "Correo de prueba" 'Cuerpo del email
    .Attachments.Add ArchivoPdf 'Archivo adjunto. El pdf creado
    .Display 'Para ver el mensaje antes de enviarlo - para enviar sin ver Send
End With

On Error GoTo 0
'**--Se borran los objetos outlook--**
Set CorreoSaliente = Nothing
Set ProgCorreo = Nothing

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True 'Excel no refresca la pantalla
    .EnableEvents = True 'Deshabilita eventos
    .DisplayAlerts = True 'Deshabilita las alertas
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque el problema aparentemente se debió a la Intranet del OP, según comentario del propio OP a la única respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

El problema creo que parte en que no lo estás enviando, te falta la instrucción `.Send`. De hecho tienes en el comentario que `display` lo visualiza pero no lo envía.

Prueba con esto:

```
With CorreoSaliente
    .To = Email
    .CC = "Correo@prueba"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Envío de su factura nº " & nfac
    .Body = "Correo de prueba"
    .Attachments.Add ArchivoPdf
    .Display
    .Send
End With
```

Comment: Gracias David, ya está solucionado, de repente ha empezado a funcionar, creo que ha sido un problema de la intranet de la empresa.